# Webservice to "ring" a phone and send a canned message

Tags: python, web-services, phone-call

I am writing a script using Python to alert the sysadmins when critical servers go down. Currently, it just sends an SMS message to the sysadmins' phones. Unfortunately, when the sysadmins are sleeping, the weak "beep" of the SMS might not be enough to wake them up.

Is there a webservice/webAPI (free/paid) that I can use to "ring" a phone, then upon pickup, play a canned message?

Note: The phone numbers to ring are *not* US phone numbers, so I can't use webservices limited to US numbers only.

Comment: I suspect that https://www.twilio.com/ can do this.

Comment: @meshy thanks! I also found out about plivo.com thanks to your mention about twilio.com. Now, if you can repost your comment as an Answer, I'll mark yours!

Comment: That looks well worth a look too, thanks `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I suspect that https://www.twilio.com can do this.

You can use their API to [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), but I must admit that I don't know how you could add the canned message.

Comment: There's a "text to speech" feature, IIRC. So yes, this fulfills my needs perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a similar, personal use case, I ended up using [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)'s [webhook](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) trigger with the [VoIP call](https://ifttt.com/voip_calls) action. The latter runs text-to-speech on a message template that you provide and can even work with variables you send as a payload in the webhook request.

It's available internationally even on the free tier and has been surprisingly reliable so far in my experience. The catch is that it's intended for personal use only, needs the IFTTT app installed on the receiver's phone and works through IP and not cellular, so it's probably not appropriate for something as mission-critical as waking up sysadmins.